# Identify the modeling software in this video?

Tags: drawing, modeling

This [video](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=isfqiYG7wiI) depicts the debut of the Steambox at CES 2013, and has a short clip starting at 0:38 that shows the product being designed.

Can anyone identify the software that is being used to create the model?

It appears that the software also uses input from a stylus on the screen. Is this common to modeling programs?